# Get Date with only given specific time - for today

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, momentjs

I need to get a datetime for a specific time at the current day.
My input is a string of the time like `13:45`

I tried to get it this way:

```
const time: String = '13:45'
const result: Date = moment(moment().format('L') + ' ' + time + ':00').toDate()
console.log(result) // Invalid Date
```

Maybe it is possible to get this done without the need of momentJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the input string, extract hours and minutes. After that, create a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance and set the hours and minutes using [`Date.prototype.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) and [`Date.prototype.setMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes) methods provided by the `Date` class.

```js
const input = '13:45';
const [hour, minutes] = input.split(':');

const today = new Date();
today.setHours(hour);
today.setMinutes(minutes);

console.log(today);
```

[`Date.prototype.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method also takes optional minutes, seconds and milliseconds as arguments. So you can just use `setHours()` method

```js
const input = '13:45';
const today = new Date();
today.setHours(...input.split(':'));

console.log(today);
```

#### Edit:

Since you are using Typescript, to avoid the error when using spread syntax as shown above in the second code snippet, you can change your code as shown below:

```
const input = '13:45';
const today = new Date();
today.setHours(...input.split(':').map(Number) as  [number, number]);

console.log(today);
```

Comment: Like the second short one, but it will complain with typescript as `setHours` needs 1 to 4 arguments

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(13);
date.setMinutes(45);

alert(date);
```

Comment: You can do it in one go: `date.setHours(13,45,0,0)`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just parse using [`moment()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```js
const time = '13:45'
const result = moment(time, 'HH:mm').format()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZsWP0vT+akWmvEMkNYgZrPHKU9Ke8nYBPC3dqONp1mY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```